# find missing extension - php on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, codeigniter

Just setup a new installation in ubuntu-12.04,then setup one codeigniter script it said nothing, eventually i found out that curl extension was missing by comparing arrays `get_loaded_extensions()` with my workmate, so i installed it.

I tried using die inside the framework system files, but nothing came out.
But, now i have installed another script, `error_reporting()` is set to E_ALL, it just says nothing. What is the best way to figure out missing extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through whole php.ini and finally found that it was

```
display_errors = off
```

so i changed it to On, and it worked!!